# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) while developing a blockchain

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain

I'm using python for implementing a blockchain and am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 137, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 98, in get_balance
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Blockchain/transaction_block.py", line 160, in get_balance
    for addr, amt, inx in txn.inputs:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

I'm trying to call the `get_balance()` function which is in the transaction_block module via my wallet.py. The `get_balance()` collects data from my transactions module `inputs` array. While there are 3 arguments in my `inputs` array but I'm getting only 2 values when I call function's inputs call. So where am I going wrong here?

transactions module:

```
def __init__(self):
        self.inputs = []
        self.outputs = []
        self.signatures = []
        self.required = []

    def add_input(self, from_address, amount, index = 0):
        self.inputs.append((from_address, amount, index))
```

transaction_block module:

```
def get_balance (pu_key, last_block):
    this_block = last_block
    bal = 0.0
    while this_block != None:
        for txn in this_block.data:
            print(txn.inputs)
            for addr, amt, inx in txn.inputs:
                if addr == pu_key:
                    bal = bal - amt
            for addr, amt in txn.outputs:
                if addr == pu_key:
                    bal = bal + amt
        this_block = this_block.previous_block
    return bal
```

If you require the entire code, I've linked it [here](https://github.com/niranjay30/Blockchain) as I've tried to keep this question clutter free. If you want to run this entire code, run the wallet.py module and you'll encounter this error.

Comment: What is the output of the print statement just above the loop?

Comment: The output is 
[]
[]
[]
[]
[(b'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAs0UOVAGs8S94vjcXK6m6\nWRoQlnQqnLoPlrZlsWd5h9Vryb8GZFgJigzxhV1hV7FDisj6GhjAZFJD+MgD8W2w\nTrKdAyQs55UZHC+NrKKgPNuhhjj0O/wOqFXUI73csfgKc74LvQmx1cbzuov9eXTd\nKQnDMCpUAbAVqkpC+pLK3m0SGSx9PxzuoipNzfE8TfRNz/BHzz4fwfqNY5a0WdpW\njkMsrmtb3F7p6ILtMDMioO6FPwNtlv2YMupQP4E2ZH/Z7eRe/VtinJIJ/HHPEXNX\nkAT8yQutqfpQ9Ex1TUNHetn1DkuP8jly97AyDAZNfF5/cnEpjvV3+79O55SJSuDo\n5wIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n', 0.1)] i.e except for the public key and the amount, I'm not getting the index

Comment: Seems like there are only 2 items in that tuple. Run the script through a debugger and figure out how & where it came from.

Comment: To potentially avoid something like this in the future, consider making `self.inputs` private so that only methods in the same class can modify it. Then you can be sure that there would be 3-tuples in it (since only one method can add to it)

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I'm developing this on an android tablet due to unavailability of my laptop with me so can't really debug anything except for the print statement. Can you please help me with this?